# c++ references array

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

I wounder how i can make this code work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void writeTable(int (&tab)[],int x){
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        cout << "Enter value " << i+1 <<endl;
        cin >> tab[i] ;
    }
}


int main(void){
    int howMany;
    cout << "How many elemets" << endl;
    cin >> howMany;

    int table[howMany];
    int (&ref)[howMany]=table;
    writeTable(ref,howMany);
    return 0;
}
```

And here are the errors that I have:

```
|4|error: parameter ‘tab’ includes reference to array of unknown bound ‘int []’|
|18|error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int (&)[]’ from expression of type ‘int [(((unsigned int)(((int)howMany) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)]’|
|4|error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void writeTable(int (&)[], int)’|
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are intending to pass the size of the array, then remove the reference

```
void f(int a[])
```

is equivalent to

```
void f(int* a)
```

so no copying will be done, if that is the concern.

If you want to take an array by reference, then you MUST specify the dimension. e.g.

```
void f(int (&a)[10])
```

Naturally, the best of the two is the third solution, which is to use std::vector's and pass them by reference, reference to const or by value if needed. HTH

Comment: Agree, passing in a pointer to the array is the way to go here.

Comment: Ok thx for help but i have one additional question in the third option I can pass dimension using a variable? If so how would look calling that function and it's prototype?

Comment: @Artur: See Prasson Saurav's answer and my comment to it. Or do you mean the vector's? For vector's see Amardeep's answer :)

Comment: @Artur - Why do you want to take the array by reference?  What are you trying to achieve here versus the simpler way of passing in the pointer?

Comment: I must do this by using references I can't user any other technique such vectors etc now I know how to do this more less. Thx for help and explanations ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly more C++ style of doing it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void writeTable(std::vector<int> &tab)
{
    int val;

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<tab.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter value " << i+1 << std::endl;
        if (std::cin >> val)
        {
            tab[i] = val;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int howMany;
    std::cout << "How many elements?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> howMany;

    std::vector<int> table(howMany);
    writeTable(table);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, but a more standard/portable way is to declare i's type as vector<int>::size_type

Comment: @Armen:  I usually use size_t but laziness set in.  I wasn't aware of the vector<>::size_type.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Amardeep: Well, USUALLY vector<T>::size_type is typedef'd as size_t, which in turn is USUALLY typedef'd as unsigned int. But there are no  guarantees

Comment: @Amardeep - +1 - you could also show the `vector<int>::iterator` alternative vs `tab[i]`

Comment: @Steve: The only reason I kept the numeric loop counter was because the original functionality displayed the index number with each read.  Otherwise a for_each or while would have been nicer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Amardeep - sure, sometimes a direct analog to the original code is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You need not specify the dimension of the array if you make `writeTable` a function template.

```
template <typename T,size_t N>
void writeTable(T (&tab)[N]) //Template argument deduction
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<N ; i++){
       // code ....
    }
}
```

.

```
int table[howMany]; // C++ doesn't have Variable Length Arrays. `howMany` must be a constant
writeTable(table);  // type and size of `table` is automatically deduced
```

Comment: but take heed that in this case you will not be able to pass dynamically allocated arrays to this function.

Comment: @Armen : Yes! Why would he need a dynamically allocated array anyway (he would use `std::vector`)?

Comment: My comment was intended for the OP, not you :)

Answer (score 1):

Following Amardeep's answer, here is a C++11 way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void writeTable(std::vector<int> &tab)
{
    int val;

    for (auto& cell : tab)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter value " << i+1 << std::endl;
        if (std::cin >> val)
        {
            cell = val;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int howMany;
    std::cout << "How many elements?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> howMany;

    std::vector<int> table(howMany);
    writeTable(table);

    return 0;
}
```

Note the range-based `for` used in `writeTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays of references are illegal, if that is what you are trying to do. It's not 100% clear to me from the title.

Comment: virtual -1: Obviously he is trying to create a reference to an array, not an array of references

Comment: @Armen - the syntax is confused enough that I respectfully disagree. It's likely that your answer is what he needs though.

Comment: @Steve: If you look at the code(let alone the syntax), it is VERY obvious that he was not trying to create an array of references

Comment: @Armen - the older I get, the less there is that is VERY obvious to me

Comment: @Steve: My youth is my enemy :)

Comment: @Armen - more of an asset than an enemy, I am sure :-)